# How to Prevent useState & useLocation from re rendering in input/text field in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

So basically my problem is that I have two pages/screens (Main & Edit). In `Main` page when I click an item then it passes it to `Edit` page using `useHistory` hooks from `react-router-dom` package. In `Edit` page I get the item using `useLocation` hooks & pass them to input field for my initial `useState`, but every time I edit/type a character in `text field` not sure if its called re render or anything else, but the `useLocation` will be passed in console. Here is my code:

**Edit Page/Screen**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

export const EditScreen = () => {
const location = useLocation().state;
console.log(location);

const [title, setTitle] = useState(location.b_title);
const [content, setContent] = useState(location.b_content);
const [category, setCategory] = useState(location.category_id);

const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  axios
  .put(`http://localhost:3001/api/v1/blog/${location.id}`, {
    blog_title: title,
    blog_content: content,
    category_id: category,
  })
  .then(alert("success edit blog"))
  .catch((err) => alert(err));
 setTitle("");
 setContent("");
 setCategory("");

};

return (
<div>
  <h1>edit blog page</h1>
  <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="title"
      value={title}
      onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="content"
      value={content}
      onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="category"
      value={category}
      onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input
      type="submit"
      value="submit"
      disabled={
        title === "" || content === "" || category === "" ? true : false
      }
    />
  </form>
</div>
 );
};
```

**Screen Shot of Console**

[image]

You can see above ss in red circle, thats the problem.

Comment: This is because every time you type you are setting a new state causing a new render which calls the `console.log`.Why is this an issue?

Comment: You are also console logging in the body of the function component as an unintentional side-effect. If you truly want to see how often a component is rendered/rerendered then console log in an `useEffect` hook. To echo what Aldo has stated, you are updating state and each update triggers a rerender, there's nothing wrong going on here, it's how React works.

Comment: @AldoSanchez Actually I ask this because I'm not sure if this is an issue  or normal thing, because I imagine if a blog web will have thousands of char every char I type then it re render the state, but if this thing normal then Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @DrewReese I tried console it in `useEffect` & it re render only once, thanks man I found what I seek for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro, We cant prevent the setState from re-rendering the component as it's the react specified default before. So you must use the debouncing technique to prevent the multiple re-renders from happening https://www.telerik.com/blogs/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript u can go through this article for better clarity of how you can do that. It's mentioned with examples clearly in the article. You can also change the event to onBlur instead of onChange we reduce the number of setStates from getting called & we reduces the re-rendering.